# How to read multiple file inputs using FileReader API in js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, filereader

I was looking for a solution though there are many answers on the same topics I was unable to figure out the problem in my code.

The problem is, I can only read the first file input using this API.
The last two inputs show undefined if I `console.log(e.target.files[1]);`

I am using vue 2. Here is the codes I have.

For the three inputs I have

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" @change="img1">
<input type="file" name="file[]" @change="img2">
<input type="file" name="file[]" @change="img3">

      img1(e){
        console.log(e.target.files[0]);
        this.readFile(e,'img1',0);
        },
       img2(e){
        console.log(e.target.files[1]);
        this.readFile(e,'img2',1);

        },
       img3(e){
         console.log(e.target.files[2]);
        this.readFile(e,'img3',2);

        },
```

Here is my readFile method

```
readFile(e,img,i) {
        let self=this;
          if(window.FileReader) {
            var file  = e.target.files[i];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            if (file) {
             let type=e.target.files[i].type;   
             console.log(type);
             if(!this.cheackType(type)){
                 this.showTypeWarn('Invalid Image Formate', 'Please Upload jpg or a png file only');
                 return
             }  
              reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            } else {
             // img.css('display', 'none');
             // img.attr('src', '');
            }
            reader.onloadend = function (e) {
              self.data.img=reader.result;
            }
          }
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: you need a dom ref, ex: `e.target.nextElementSibling.files[0]`. using `id` would be simplest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `console.log(e.target.files[i]);` you are accessing the i-th file of the element that fired the event. You should try with `console.log(e.target.files[0]);` to access the first file of each input.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think this at all. :) Thanks again !